# Pass Accent character in querystring NodeJS and Request Module

Tags: node.js, url, request, query-string

I'm using Request module in my nodejs express app, and i need to pass in the querystring any accented character (Ex: josé) but when the other client gets the request it gets an unknown character (?).

If i pass the same url by browser or postman the client gets the correct accent character.

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var url = 'http://mypathtotheurl?var=josé';

const optionsStart = {
              url: url,
              method: "GET",
              encoding: "binary",
              headers: {
                "Content-type": "applcation/pdf"
              }
        };
      request(optionsStart).then(function(body, data) {
        //my logic working as expected except for show special chars
     }
```

With the browser or postman get the correct response, by request module gets unknow character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quick solution enconding the url in the request method:

```
var url = 'http://mypathtotheurl?var=josé';

url = encodeURI(url)
```